# Split comma separated column data into additional columns which has more than 50 fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, delimiter

So I am trying to Split comma separated column data into additional columns.

```
select max(array_length(regexp_split_to_array(tags, ','), 1)) from employee 

    The value is 61.
```

How can I change the below that I don't need to type a[xx] 61 times?

```
select a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6]
from (
    select regexp_split_to_array(tags, ',')
    from employee
) as dt(a)
```

Comment: Don't put the results in separate columns, put them into separate rows.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: If you need 60 columns, you need to type the expression for each and every of them. There is no way around it.

Comment: You could do this using dynamic SQL to build a string which you then execute, but it is probably easier to simply  type it in ...

Comment: @user10324767 . . . `regexp_split_to_table()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @gordon-linoff pointed out, you can use `regexp_split_to_table`

A code example:

```
create table employee (tags varchar(50));

insert into employee values ('one,two,three'),('cow,chicken,rooster');`

select * 
from (
    select regexp_split_to_table(tags, ',')
    from employee
) as t
```

Result:

```
 regexp_split_to_table
-----------------------
 one
 two
 three
 cow
 chicken
 rooster
```